# Python OpenCV imwrite 0 bytes image depends on execution dir

Tags: python, opencv

I have written a small script to convert a RGB image to grey.
When I run the script in terminal form current dir (`python3 image.py`), it works perfectly fine.

But when I rum it from a dir lower like `python3 proc/image.py` it creates a result image with 0 bytes size.

here is the code of `image.py`

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

def sw(name):
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    img_path = os.path.join(dir_path, name)
    print(img_path)
    img = cv2.imread(name, 0)
    rslt_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "schwarn_g.jpeg")
    print(rslt_path)
    cv2.imwrite(rslt_path, img)
    return img


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sw('schwarn.jpeg')
```

Can somebody explain this behavior?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the `image` that you want to work on with the following line:

```
img = cv2.imread(name, 0)
```

And since your `script` always calls the `function` with this line:

```
sw('schwarn.jpeg')
```

you are always trying to open the `img`: `schwarn.jpg` from the **same directory** that you are running the `script`. All your `os.path` joining is affecting where the `grayscale` image is outputted to - not where the original image is read from.

This means that since the program is trying to open the `img` in the same `directory` that you are running the `script`, the `img` can **only** be loaded in when you are running the `script` in the same directory as the `img`. Therefore, when you try and run the `script` in a different `directory`, the `img` cannot be read in and the resulting `greyscale` image has no contents...

Comment: Thank you. Just changed on line `img_path = os.path.join(dir_path, name)` to `img_path = os.path.join(dir_path, img_path)`. I didn't saw that.